# Start process and echo to it afterwards

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I would like to send more input to a command, after having called it. (the command keeps a stream open to a server)

How would I start a command that opens in another window and then afterwards be able to echo to that window from my batch-file?

Answer (score 0):

In the light of your further comments, maybe you can do something like this:

**Server:**

```
START "Server" "ServerProgram.exe" /WAIT
```

**In "Heartbeat and streaming starter" window:**

```
CONTROL.BAT | nc localhost 10000
```

Where the following file is saved as CONTROL.BAT

```
@echo off
echo Get started please
:top
echo Pulse
sleep 3
goto top
```

Basically it echoes a "Start streaming" command followed by "Heartbeat" every 3 seconds into netcat. So the server will effectively be doing something equivalent to this:

```
nc -l localhost 10000
Start streaming     # 3 secs
Heartbeat           # 3 secs
Heartbeat           # 3 secs
Heartbeat           # 3 secs
```

Comment: I was using netcat to send to a TCP server, but after sending the first message and recieving a stream as respose. I would like to be able to write to it while recieving a stream. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by "the command keeps a stream open to the server". What stream? stdin? a socket? a pipe? And also what server? Where does the command try to read _FROM_ as that will determine where your batch file needs to write to.

Comment: It tries to read from a localhost server streaming a socket (using nc).

Comment: So when you say you want to "be able to echo to that window" you actually mean you want to send further data to a port on which the process is listening? So why can't you send the further data by doing "echo further data| nc someport"

Comment: Or is the problem that you can't work the "START" command in Windows?

Comment: The problem is that nc cannot run in two windows at the same time. If I run it in one window, it will wait for the process to finish (which it won't because it's streaming from the socket), and if I use start to run it in another window it will fail because it cannot run in two places at the same time. If you know how this should be done, please post some sample code. It's very possible that it's some small stupid mistake :-)

Comment: Mmmm... you have confused me now. Netcat can run in as many windows as you like, as long as they are using different ports. How about posting your batch file?

Comment: Sorry. I have been quite confusing in my explanation. I need to start a socket to an application on localhost (which will then interface with an USB device). The application on localhost need to be sent a heartbeat every 3 seconds, else it will stop streaming data, and shutdown the device.

What I thought I could do was to open nc in another window and then just make the batch file "type" in first the initial command that ask it to push data, and then send the heartbeat at intervals of 3 seconds.But that's maybe not possible? I can of course also send you my code :-)